# send a gif in a message

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to know if I can send a  gif in ros message. I know that I can send an image, but I do not know if a gif I can send. If I can send a git, how do you send it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252885/send-a-gif-in-a-message/) by [ines](https://answers.ros.org/users/29152/ines/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-01-24**:
Its possible to send images and videos, so I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to send gifs. However it would require not only a custom message type, but also I imagine you would have to modify image_transport in order to support gifs. I don't think this would be a minor task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are lots of ways to do this, all of varying complexity and difficult; which one you choose depends largely on the end goal that you're trying to achieve.

If you just want to transfer gifs between your nodes, you could just make a custom message type and stuff the gif data into it. (or, if your nodes will always run on the same computer, just send the absolute path)

If you want compatibility with existing tools like image_transport , image_view or rviz, you'll need to do a bit more work to make it possible to encode and decode gifs into a format that the existing tools can use. You might need to write a custom image_transport that uses gif compression, or you might need to write or adapt one of the existing rviz plugins.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0